# Grabbing Mysql data from one table and showing it for a specific user with a specific ID

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm hoping to get help here because I have no ideas whatsoever.
So I have this problem.It's for a game, doesn't matter what game it is...so I have a user that logged in lets say by ID 1. Every user registered gets a different ID.No users have the same one.That's how my UCP knows what user has what username. So there's a table - `serverplayers` and there's a table `vehicles`.

Serverplayers - holds the user ID ant all other things connected to his account.(**no car id**, nothing)

vehicles - holds vehicle ID's and their owners **name**. Let's say user has a name created in game - James.

So there's a car with vModel - 400 and vOwner - James.That's the problem, how do I show to that user what car he has. If that is even possible :(

Comment: look into normalised data structures and querying them with INNER JOINS... that should push you forward

Comment: This is called a `join`.  I would suggest that you study a bit about SQL before trying to use it for an application.  This is very basic SQL.

Comment: Im going to try out both of the suggestions and give my feedback ASAP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read up on it here:
http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_inner.asp

By the looks of it, you should get a statement like this:

```
SELECT users.*, vehicles.* 
FROM users
INNER JOIN vehicles
ON users.user_id=vehicles.user_id
```

Something like that, try it out.

Answer (score 1):

In most cases you want your unique field to be the field that is represented in both tables.

So I would suggest reformatting your table. Instead of having your vehicle table set up with the users name, put the owner user ID in the vehicle table.

So your tables would look like

### Users

```
user_id
name
```

### Vehicles

```
vehicle_id
vehicle_name
user_id
```

Then you would join your two tables on the user_id

See here for more on joins

http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html

And after reading the comments, you really should look into relational database design:

http://webs.wofford.edu/whisnantdm/Courses/CS101/PDF/Database/Relational_database_concepts.pdf
http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/knowing-just-enough-about-relational-databases.html
http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/tools-and-tips/relational-databases-for-dummies/